# Linear model with repeated measures factors

Tags: r, mixed-models

I have a dataframe `df`

```
    df<-structure(list(subject = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
49L, 50L, 51L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
51L), sex = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), age = c(29L, 54L, 67L, 
36L, 48L, 37L, 25L, 46L, 37L, 33L, 25L, 26L, 28L, 59L, 46L, 50L, 
55L, 56L, 37L, 30L, 38L, 30L, 50L, 39L, 29L, 46L, 48L, 46L, 55L, 
32L, 66L, 35L, 48L, 54L, 38L, 31L, 42L, 36L, 27L, 63L, 45L, 31L, 
26L, 38L, 43L, 52L, 36L, 43L, 65L, 46L, 42L, 29L, 54L, 67L, 36L, 
48L, 37L, 25L, 46L, 37L, 33L, 25L, 26L, 28L, 59L, 46L, 50L, 55L, 
56L, 37L, 30L, 38L, 30L, 50L, 39L, 29L, 46L, 48L, 46L, 55L, 32L, 
66L, 35L, 48L, 54L, 38L, 31L, 42L, 36L, 27L, 63L, 45L, 31L, 26L, 
38L, 43L, 52L, 36L, 43L, 65L, 46L, 42L), edu = c(4L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
6L, 1L, 3L), biz_exp = c(5L, 15L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 0L, 5L, 8L, 
5L, 0L, 8L, 3L, 23L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 11L, 4L, 4L, 11L, 3L, 15L, 4L, 
4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 13L, 2L, 13L, 6L, 8L, 27L, 7L, 3L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 
4L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 15L, 18L, 30L, 9L, 14L, 18L, 21L, 16L, 5L, 15L, 
3L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 0L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 0L, 8L, 3L, 23L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 
11L, 4L, 4L, 11L, 3L, 15L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 13L, 2L, 13L, 
6L, 8L, 27L, 7L, 3L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 15L, 18L, 30L, 
9L, 14L, 18L, 21L, 16L), turnov = c(36L, NA, 12L, 9L, 48L, 9L, 
8L, 24L, 4L, 250L, NA, 600L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 4L, 250L, 
200L, 50L, 150L, 48L, NA, 9L, 6L, 2L, NA, NA, 3L, 7L, 23L, 75L, 
7L, 5L, NA, 20L, 450L, 5L, 32L, 21L, 12L, 6L, 4L, 24L, 7L, 10L, 
12L, 12L, 14L, 18L, 36L, NA, 12L, 9L, 48L, 9L, 8L, 24L, 4L, 250L, 
NA, 600L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 4L, 250L, 200L, 50L, 150L, 48L, 
NA, 9L, 6L, 2L, NA, NA, 3L, 7L, 23L, 75L, 7L, 5L, NA, 20L, 450L, 
5L, 32L, 21L, 12L, 6L, 4L, 24L, 7L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 18L), 
    loc_pr = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 
    4L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L
    ), type = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L
    ), age_rec = c(2L, 4L, 4L, 100L, 4L, 100L, 100L, 4L, 100L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 100L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
    3L, 100L, 27L, 100L, 100L, 4L, 2L, 100L, 2L, 4L, 30L, 3L, 
    2L, 59L, 8L, 100L, 27L, 3L, 59L, 2L, 59L, 3L, 59L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 64L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 100L, 4L, 100L, 100L, 4L, 100L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 100L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
    3L, 100L, 27L, 100L, 100L, 4L, 2L, 100L, 2L, 4L, 30L, 3L, 
    2L, 59L, 8L, 100L, 27L, 3L, 59L, 2L, 59L, 3L, 59L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 64L, 3L), biz_exp_rec = c(2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
    4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), turnov_rec = structure(c(3L, NA, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 2L, NA, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, 4L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, NA, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, NA, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", 
    "3", "4", "MA"), class = "factor"), bundle = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), investment = c(86L, 
    100L, 100L, 75L, 100L, 59L, 68L, 86L, 80L, 100L, 86L, 100L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 93L, 64L, 100L, 24L, 18L, 89L, 
    75L, 80L, 29L, 54L, 65L, 100L, 27L, 59L, 30L, 59L, 43L, 59L, 
    59L, 5L, 26L, 100L, 75L, 59L, 5L, 59L, 74L, 59L, 79L, 75L, 
    75L, 86L, 66L, 86L, 55L, 100L, 68L, 1L, 75L, 1L, 1L, 79L, 
    1L, 54L, 48L, 33L, 55L, 90L, 85L, 39L, 70L, 1L, 45L, 54L, 
    33L, 3L, 44L, 75L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 96L, 26L, 1L, 23L, 66L, 
    1L, 89L, 83L, 52L, 61L, 1L, 88L, 45L, 72L, 60L, 1L, 60L, 
    2L, 86L, 10L, 63L, 1L, 88L)), .Names = c("subject", "sex", 
"age", "edu", "biz_exp", "turnov", "loc_pr", "type", "age_rec", 
"biz_exp_rec", "turnov_rec", "bundle", "investment"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-102L))
```

In this dataframe `investment` is my dependent variable and the other variables are my independent variables. My subjects are crossed within type of bundle. First of all, I would like know whether my subjects do bundle or not (bundle= 1 means that people bundle and bundle=0 means that people do not bundle), it will have an effect on the investment.

I have done this mixed effect linear model but I am not sure if this is correct as my p-value are equal to zero.

```
library(nlme) 
model <- lme(investment~bundle, random = ~1|subject/bundle, data=df)
```

I have also tried to make an anova with repeated measures as such: 
`aov(investment~bundle+ Error(subject/bundle), data=df)`
It works but not sure if the model formula is right

Anyone could help me with that?

Comment: I think you would do better to ask this over on CrossValidated.

Comment: Well. It is also a coding question in my opinion. But Yeah I can also post it on cross validated

Comment: have you thought about plotting your data. Would a p-value = 0 make sense? but like @darwind suggested CrossValidated would better.

Comment: Yes I did and they seem to significantly different.

Comment: a couple of things to verify,1) did you test for normality?, 2) are the subjects in bundle 0 different from bundle 1? if yes, I believe (but double check) you will have to change the name of those subjects. e.g. for bundle 0, b01 to b051 and for bundle 1, b11 to b151. Otherwise it's cross.

Comment: @MLavoie. My subjects are nested within type of bundle.

Comment: "I am not sure if this is correct as my p-value are equal to zero" sounds like a statistics question, not a coding question. As does "I want to see if my other independent variables influence the investment".

Comment: that's what I thought, rename your subjects and rerun your model

Comment: @MLavoie. But my subjects in bundle 0 are not different from bundle 1 so no need to change the name of the subjects right?

Comment: ok, sorry. if there are the same, no need to rename, but there are not nested but crossed

Comment: @MLavoie. So it seems that my data are not normal distributed. p<0.05 for the shapiro test. Any idea what I can do? it is more like a Bernoulli distribution

Comment: you can try to transform (log, sqrt, etc) it. But this really a statistical question.